# Can electric field inside a battery be zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits

Consider a cell of EMF $e$ and internal resistance $R$.
In case of discharging, terminal potential difference is given by :
              $V=e-IR$.
If $e=IR$ then voltage is zero.

Since $$v=\int E\cdot dr$$ where $E$ is electric field)
and $dr$ cant be zero.

This means that electric field is equal to zero. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you just solved for the theoretical maximum current that a battery can deliver. This is an extreme limit that may not be realized exactly in reality, but you can get close. The battery will get hot if you do this. A real battery could be damaged and you should not do this at home.

Comment: Will there be electric field inside the battery or not?

Comment: Ideally, yes. In the real world, maybe not exactly.